# Generate styled Map Tiles

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm trying to create an app that contains a small map that should always work without internet connection for four different zoom levels.

To do this I know that I have to generate map tiles in png (or similar) to be used later on by Leaflet (or OpenLayers/Mapbox GL JS). This is no issue, because using Maperitive I can generate map tiles with given bounds and min and max zoom levels.

My problem is that I need to use a different style for roads, buildings, etc. To edit this style I used Mapbox Studio online editor and generated a JSON file with my custom styles.

What I need to do is **apply this style before generating the resulting tiles**, but I don't know how to do this.

Below there's a diagram for what I'm thinking about.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55685/generate-styled-map-tiles

Comment: Yes, @scai you're right it's a crosspost.  I created a question there because nobody had replied here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution is at [@PlaneMad Answer in OSM Help website](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/55685/generate-styled-map-tiles/55695)

I couldn't use the styles generated with Mapbox Studio but instead another solution was used.

What i did:

1. Go to OpenStreetMap and export the boundingbox i wanted to work with.
2. Open the downloaded osm file in Maperitive.
3. Map > Switch to Rules > googlemaps
4. Map > Edit Rendering Rules and now i edited the styles as a wanted.
5. Run command: `generate-tiles minzoom=14 maxzoom=17 resolution=2 bounds="..."`

Now in Maperitive folder there's a new folder called Tiles and inside there's tiles for each zoom level. To use those tiles offline just point Leaflet to local filesystem with: `L.tileLayer('./{z}/{x}/{y}.png');`